# Connecting Dynamically Created Subviews to IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I have UIImage Subviews that are created while the App is running

```
     UIImageView *newBlock = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    newBlock.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 58.0, 58.0);
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:newBlock];
```

However because they do not exist in the Interface Builder (or at least I can't find them) I cannot connect my IBOutlet to the new images so they move based on a timer

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.001) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
pos = CGPointMake(0.0,0.05);
```

...

```
- (void) onTimer {

blocks.center = CGPointMake(blocks.center.x+pos.x,blocks.center.y+pos.y)
```

I've been considering a way to link them via code and not in the Interface Builder however have not found any details to date on how this is done. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if mine or anyone else's answer solved your question don't forget to mark as top answer and upvote it so other ppl with the same issue will know the solution. If not add a comment and ask for more help

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect a view with the interface builder programatically, if I were you I'd try to think of a different approach to your problem.

Comment: Create a instance variable or property for UIImageView *newBlock. And refer to it in the whole scope.

Comment: Could you explain further how this works thanks? Sorry I have little experience to date

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically connect them to IBOutlets. Why not simply store all the instances in an array as variables ?

```
NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: X];

...

[imageViews addObject: imageView];

...

for(UIView *view in imageViews)
{
   ...
}
```